# The value is not a function and cannot be applied F#

Tags: c#, f#, c#-to-f#

I have the following extension method:

```
module AzureTableExtensions =

    type IServiceCollection with

        member this.AddAzureTableStorage(options : Action<AzureTableClientOptions>) =
            this.Configure<AzureTableClientOptions>(options) !> ignore
            
            this.AddScoped<IAzureTableClient>(Func<_,_>(fun (sp: IServiceProvider) ->
                    let options = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AzureTableClientOptions>>()
                    AzureTableClient(options.Value) :> IAzureTableClient)) !> ignore

            this
```

And it is sending me the error that I mention in the title both in the Configure and in the AddScoped. Its similar in C# has no problem.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddAzureTableStorage(
            this IServiceCollection services,
            Action<AzureTableClientOptions> setupOptions
        )
        {
            services.Configure<AzureTableClientOptions>(setupOptions);
            services.AddScoped<IAzureTableClient>(provider =>
            {
                var options = provider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AzureTableClientOptions>>();
                return new AzureTableClient(options.Value);
            });

            return services;
        }
```

I'm new to F# I understand that the language does not do the implicit conversions that one is used to in C#, if you could help me correct it.

Comment: Where does the error arise exactly?

Comment: Here this.Configure<AzureTableClientOptions>(options) !> ignore and here  this.AddScoped<IAzureTableClient>(Func<_,_>(fun (sp: IServiceProvider) ->
                    let options = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AzureTableClientOptions>>()
                    AzureTableClient(options.Value) :> IAzureTableClient)) !> ignore

Comment: What is `!>` in your code? Do you mean `|>`?

Comment: Yes, it's just what I'm seeing, I think the typography I have doesn't help. I'll try if that's it.

Comment: The ignore seems strange. That makes the func return unit instead of the client